# Select lines where nested table column meets a condition

Tags: sql, oracle, user-defined-types

**v** is defined as follows: `create or replace type v is table of number` and **emp**  is a table which contains a column of type v.

I want to select the lines where `v.count` is 3, but I will get a compilation error. Is it because `v.count` is PL/SQL code?

I tried putting the code inside an anonymous block but it still didn't work.

Is using cursors the only solution?

```
 SELECT *
 FROM emp
 WHERE V.COUNT = 3;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why not tell us *what* error you got? Show us the table DDL too - is the column actually called `v`, the same as the type name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`cardinality()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CARDINALITY.html):

> `CARDINALITY` returns the number of elements in a nested table. The return type is `NUMBER`. If the nested table is empty, or is a null collection, then `CARDINALITY` returns `NULL`.

So you can do:

```
SELECT *
FROM emp
WHERE cardinality(V) = 3;
```

Quick demo:

```
create or replace type v is table of number
/

create table emp (id number, v v)
nested table v store as v_tab;

insert into emp (id, v) values (1, v(1));
insert into emp (id, v) values (2, v(1,2));
insert into emp (id, v) values (3, v(1,2,3));
insert into emp (id, v) values (4, v(1,2,3,4));

column v format a30
set feedback 1

SELECT *
FROM emp
WHERE cardinality(V) = 3;

        ID V                             
---------- ------------------------------
         3 V(1, 2, 3)                    

1 row selected.
```

Answer (score 1):

I like Alex's cardinality answer, here is another approach:

```
create or replace type num_type as table of number;

create table table_with_num_type
(
ids num_type,
val varchar2(100)
)
nested table ids store as ids_tab ;

insert into table_with_num_type(ids, val) values (num_type(1,2,3), 'TEST1');
insert into table_with_num_type(ids, val) values (num_type(4,5,6,7), 'TEST2');
commit;

select t.val, count(t2.column_value) as num_count
from table_with_num_type t, table(t.ids) t2
group by t.val
having count(t2.column_value) = 3;
```

Result:

```
VAL NUM_COUNT
TEST1   3
```